# how to pause the timer thread

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I want to pause the "timer" thread....or i can say want to put it into  "wait"  mode and then notify after something gets completed.

`Timer _catchTimer = new Timer();
CatchAppNameTimer _catchTimerTask = new CatchAppNameTimer(_catchTimer);
_catchTimer.schedule(_catchTimerTask, 0, 5000);`

My "TimerTask ( _catchTimerTask ) " everytime shows a Popup screen ....that popup screen has two buttons - Unlock, Cancel.

basically i want that until user clicks on.... one of the Unlock / cancel btn,  Time thread gets set on wait mode..... when user click one of the Unlock / Cancel button............ only after then Time thread gets notifiy.

Currently I am using a boolean variable in run method of "timertask" ..... to handle the deadlock situation...... that  is TimerTask get called  in every few secs......even when popup screen already shown..........

As follows :

```
public void run() { 


GlobalSingleton obj = null; 
  obj = GlobalSingleton.getInstance(); 
  if( obj.getShowDialog() ) 
        return;

   unlockField();
}
```

when first time "unlockFiled()" called........i set a boolean variable as true (using Runtime Store) ....... which value is retrived by getShowDialog() method.  and in

`fieldChanged(Field field, int context) { }` method of both Unlock / Cancel button......... i set the boolean var's value as false......  by calling ...

`GlobalSingleton obj = null;
obj = GlobalSingleton.getInstance();
obj.setShowDialog(false);`

But the right approch is "timer-task" should not be started  again....... untilll user press either Unblock / Cancel button and control gets out of the `fieldChanged(Field field, int context) { }` method.

shuld i use a differnet thread to handle the....wait - notify operations on the Timer object....on the basis of a boolean variable.  i hv already tried this approach.......... but cant get a solution...

i'll be gratefull for any suggestions....

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks BOSS and Alexey for ur contribution, I have solved my problem with a continuously running thread having sleep for 1 sec.

My solution is given on -
[solution](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-pause-the-timer-thread/m-p/1744855#M200757)
or at : [main thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-pause-the-timer-thread/m-p/1743415)
Please vote if u find my solution helpful as I need some reputations for start chat on blackberry rooms.

thnks.

Answer (score 0):

As I undestood you have thread that is listen for some evenst and execute this events. Mayby producer-consumer pattern will help:

1 You have producer that put messages to queue

2 You have BlockingQueue where your messages are stored

3 You have thread that read messages from BlockingQueue (if queue is empty thread is wait for message) and depends on message it show/hide your dialog.

Think this will be simplest and clear implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Monitor you TimerTask with another Thread.And specify your condition some sort of while loop when it satisfy just notify your Timetask to stop the Job.